# DragDropEffects.Scroll: why -2147483648 not 8?

Tags: c#, .net, com, enums, ole

A standard enumeration in `System.Windows.Forms`:

```
[Flags]
public enum DragDropEffects
{
    Scroll = -2147483648,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The combination of the System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Link,
    //     System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Move, and System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Scroll
    //     effects.
    All = -2147483645,
    None = 0,
    Copy = 1,
    Move = 2,
    Link = 4,
}
```

Quite a strange value for Scroll, don't you think?

As I understand these values all come from ["the old times" of COM\OLE DROPEFFECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693457(VS.85).aspx)... But why were they chosen so in the first place? Did author try to reserve the interval between 8 and 0x80000000 for something? Is it usefule somehow or is there an interesting story behind it or it's just another long-lived illustration of the YAGNI principle?

Answer (score 1):

It is a status flag, separate from the principal drop effects (Copy/Move/Link).  Short from leaving room for future drop effects, picking the high bit allows a trick like checking if the value is negative.  Same kind of idea as an HRESULT or the GetAsyncKeyState return value.

Comment: What's that trick with the negative value and HRESULT? I don't think I remember that... =(

Comment: If it is less than zero then the call failed.  That's what the FAILED(hr) macro does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like an "interesting" hack of some sort.  Common sense would suggest using 8, but maybe there's some Windows version related reason why 8 couldn't be used, and so the author used -2147483645 (-0x80000000) instead.  It's not *that* unusual a number - whoever wrote it is just starting with a binary '1' from the high significant end rather than the low significant end.

Perhaps scrolling was regarded in some other group of drag/drop effects to copy/move/link, and so the author wanted to place it at the other end of the word, along with any other future similarly different effects.

Maybe there's some awful piece of logic somewhere to test to see if a DragDropEffects variable is greater than zero (intending to mean "anything that isn't none"), and Scroll should not fall in that range?

Bit of a mystery.  At the very least you'd think they would put the constant in as hex, to show it's not just some *totally* random number.

Comment: Whether it's shown in decimal or hex is a consequence of the decompiler options used, and tells you nothing about the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

This allows a quick check for > 0 in order to know whether Copy, Move, or Link are being invoked.  It excludes None as well as Scroll.